# Joomla Code Cleanup on Save gives javascript infinite Loop error?

Tags: joomla, tinymce

I have some large joomla content on my site. Published through tinyMCE editor. On Save it gives an infinite loop error. When i change parameter code cleanup on save to never. The error does not occurs but then it inserts unwanted things in my code. How can i get this resolved. Has somebody faced similiar issue.

Comment: can you show use some code (and the exact error message)?

Comment: Code. Joomla is a content management System having its default content editor to publish content. This answer can be best given by someone who knows joomla and/or tinyMCE. I didnt coded anything.

Comment: i am a tinymce developer, but without the corresponing joomla code i cannot help

Comment: Try out JCE editor and check if the error is present ...

Answer (score 0):

Do not insert code with any editor! Swich to "No editor" option in your profil page to insert the required code.